# Type "ContasML" is missing from type ContasML[]: length, pop, concat and 26 more

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tendo o seguinte erro no meu editor visual studio code:
Type "ContasML" is missing from type ContasML[]: length, pop, concat and 26 more

**Meu modelo:**

```
export class ContasML{
    id: number
    email: string;
    senha: string;
}
```

**Inicialização:**

```
  contasML: ContasML[] = new Array();
```

Eu devo chamar a função cancelaOperacaoContaML para limpar os campos da tela, eu tento criar uma nova instância da classe

```
  cancelaOperacaoContaML(){
    this.contasML = new ContasML();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está atribuindo um objeto a uma variável declarada como Array. Considerando que você quer um array, atualize seu método para o seguinte:

```
cancelaOperacaoContaML(){
  this.contasML = new Array<ContasML>();
}
```